# Angular 4 async with loading and display when empty

Tags: angular, async-await

I have an Angular component that gets a service `CatalogService`injected:

```js
export class CatalogListComponent implements OnInit {
  catalog$: Observable<MovieResponseItem[]>;
  constructor(private catalogService: CatalogService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.catalog$ = this.catalogService.userCatalog;
  }
}
```

This service returns an `Observable<MovieResponseItem[]>` on property `userCatalog`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CatalogService {
  get userCatalog(): Observable<MovieResponseItem[]> {
    return this._userCatalogSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

The `MovieResponseItem`is just a simple interface:

```js
export interface MovieResponseItem {
  title: string;
}
```

Now I want to iterate the items and display a loading animation while the catalog queries the underlying service for data (that takes some time) - this works. This is the template used:

```xml
<div *ngIf="(catalog$ | async)?.length > 0; else loading">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of catalog$ | async">
     <div>{{item.title}}</div>
   <ng-container>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>loading animation...</ng-template>
```

This obviously displays the #loading template while the async is awaiting data. If the observable returns data, it iterates over the catalog values.

But now I want to separate this into this behaviour:

- while we await data, display the loading animation
- if we have a response from the service and the returned list is empty, show an information text (like "your catalog is empty") and do not iterate (as there is no data)
- if we have a response from the service and the returned list has values, iterate the items (as in current state)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can add another `<ng-container *ngIf="catalogService.userCatalog.length == 0">
     <div>your catalogue response is empty</div>
   <ng-container>` just below your ngFor container.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```xml
 <div *ngIf="catalog$ | async as catalog; else loading">
  <ng-container *ngIf="catalog.length; else noItems">
    <div *ngFor="let item of catalog">{{item.title}}</div>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #noItems>No Items!</ng-template>
 </div>
 <ng-template #loading>loading animation...</ng-template>
```

This should do the trick. Better to use as few async pipes as possible and just declare it "as" a template variable you can use where ever. Otherwise the stream will be executed once per async pipe which is a bad practice and could create unneeded http calls if this is http backed.

*edit for the syntax error

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately This never displays the loading template but always the noItem while waiting for the Observable answer.

Comment: the structure and scope needs to be just like i laid it out or it won't work. loading needs to be outside the async on ngIf and the noItems needs to be inside the async scope but outside the catalog.length scope

Comment: also I'm not sure what the source subject of your catalog$ observable is, but if it's a behavior subject, then this will never be "loading" as the value is always there immediately. if this is the case then you need to initialize it to null rather than [] as [] is "truthy" while null is falsey

Comment: Understood, probably my observable is the problem. I use, as you stated, a `BehaviorSubject<MovieResponseItem[]>` that is used with `.asObservable()`. I'll try to refactor this.

Comment: you can still initialize it to null as every value in typescript is nullable by default.  You can also add .filter(v => !!v) to only pass through non null values which gives you the timing benefits of both subject types

Comment: but if your goal is to tell the difference between the empty array you initialized vs the one you got from the server... well then you'll need another variable as two empty arrays are of course going to be indistinguishable

Comment: Alright, good hint with the BehaviorSubject and the null stuff. I'll have a look into that, as this explains the missing loading display.

Comment: This answer works perfectly for me with my app (Ionic, Angular4, Firestore Observables)

Comment: my problem with this is it always flashes the empty message before displaying the items.

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer you're doing something wrong if that is the case. probably using the wrong type of subject or passing an empty array value at some point

Comment: @bryan60 i'm using ngrx selectors, i believe it's because change detection runs twice. I'm still debugging it.

Edit: it does, i just add console.log to it

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer Change detection isn't the issue. the empty message will only display if the observable has emitted and it emitted an empty array, regardless of how many cd cycles run. the problem is that at some point the state of that observable is an empty array when it should not be. ngrx is implemented as a behavior subject, so, im guessing your initial state is empty array when it should be null or undefined

Comment: @bryan60, i just found it. On fetching the items, i dispatched an action that changes the loading flag, and then when the items are fetched, dispatched another success action that adds the items in the store. So basically, 1 action to update the loading flag and 1 action to update the items

Comment: the number of actions also shouldn't matter. what matters is using an empty array as a plceholder for an array that is still unloaded.

Comment: @bryan60 if i replace the *ngIf="items.length" to *ngIf="items", then it works. It kinda makes sense since javascript treats an empty array as truthy so it won't flash the "else" part.

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer that doesn't make any sense. it shouldn't be reaching that block if falsey as it should be caught by the outter block to show the loading display, and it means the empty message will never be shown... you're obviously doing things in a different way that is outside the scope of this question and answer. so you should probably ask one about your specific issue if you're having one

Comment: @bryan60 yeah it definitely was not displaying, i was wrong. Thanks, i'll just debug my code for now. I'll raise an issue if i can't get it done.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm.. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14479

Just throw in another ngIf - else condition.

```
<div *ngIf="(catalog$ | async);  else loading;">
   <div *ngIf="catalog$.length == 0; else empty;">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of catalog$ | async">
         <div>{{item.title}}</div>
      <ng-container>
   </div>
   <ng-template #empty>empty animation...</ng-template>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>loading animation...</ng-template>
```

Comment: catalog$ is an observable of a list so it will never have a length

Comment: Thank you, as seen on the other answer my `catalog$` is never null (currently, will adjust it) thus the laoding animation is never displayed. Good linked issue!