# Angular 5: Search with Async Pipe - show loading indicator

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Im am implementing a search-field with `async` in Anglur 5. When the user begins typing in the search-box, the loading-indicator should show up. And when the results have arrived, the indicator should be hidden.

I tried this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434313/angular-4-async-with-loading-and-display-when-empty), but then loading indicator is visible, even if the user has not typed anything.
So what is the best way to implement this?

My Template:

```
<mdl-textfield #searchBox (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" type="text" placeholder="Nach Kurs, Beteuer, Studiengruppe suchen..."></mdl-textfield>
<!--[...]-->
<div *ngIf="courses$ | async as courses">
  <ng-container *ngIf="courses.length; else noItems">
      <app-course *ngFor="let course of courses" [course]="course" [addAble]="true"></app-course>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #noItems><em>Kein Ergebniss für "{{searchBox.value}}"</em></ng-template>
</div>
```

The Component:

```
public courses$: Observable<Course[]>;
public searchCourseTerm = new Subject<string>();
public serachLoadingIndicator: boolean = false;

constructor(private courseService: CourseService) { }

gOnInit() {
  this.courses$ = this.searchCourseTerm.pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((term: string) => this.courseService.searchCourse(term)),
  );
}

search(term: string ){
  this.searchCourseTerm.next(term);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.courses$ = this.searchCourseTerm.pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(() => this.searching = true)
    switchMap((term: string) => this.courseService.searchCourse(term)),
    tap(() => this.searching = false)
  );
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: More like `finalize(() => this.searching = false)`.

Comment: @estus I'd say that `this.courseService.searchCourse(term)`should rather be something like `this.courseService.searchCourse(term).pipe(catchError(() => of([]))`, otherwise, the pipeline would be completely broken is a search ever fails.

Comment: Replacing an error with an empty list might be dangerous depending on the context. Say you're developing a healthcare software and loading patient allergies. If request fails, user is shown an empty list and they interpret it as patient having no allergies. You need to design an error handling strategy that is appropriate for your software.