# Add loading functionality to Angular App

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement loading whenever I type on the search bar of my app. But it seems that only the first 'tap' function is being called and setting the loading value to true. I end up with true not being set to false. Any help/suggestion on how I should do this?

Followed this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609228/angular-5-search-with-async-pipe-show-loading-indicator) .

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CourseService } from './course-service';

import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, Subject, from } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, tap, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'explore',
  templateUrl: './explore.component.html'
})

export class ExploreComponent implements OnInit {
  loading: boolean = false;

  private searchString$ = new Subject<string>();
  courses$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private ar: ActivatedRoute, public cs: CourseService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.courses$ = this.searchString$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => this.loading = true),
      switchMap((term: string) => this.cs.getCoursess(term)),
      tap(() => this.loading = false)
    );
  }

  search(text: string) {
    this.searchVal = text;
    this.searchString$.next(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: add catchError to be sure in case of error your loading becomes false: pipe(...,catchError(()=>this.loading=false)

Answer (score 0):

Try Do

```
this.courses$ = this.searchString$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      ,do( () => this.loading = true)
      switchMap((term: string) => this.cs.getCoursess(term)),
      ,do( () => this.loading = false )
    );
```

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html
do and tap are the same things