# ngIf async pipe Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I have this Code

```
 <div>
<div *ngIf="(imgDoc$ | async) ?.photoURL; then DisplayImgContainer;">
    <p>No Image</p>
</div>
<ng-template #DisplayImgContainer>
    <img [src]="(imgDoc$ | async) ?.photoURL"/> 
    Image Display 
</ng-template>
```

But this error is returning:

```
GET http://localhost:8100/null 404 (Not Found)
```

if you change to this code the image is normally displayed:

```
<div>
  <img [src]="(imgDoc$ | async) ?.photoURL"/> 
</div>
```

What's wrong with the asynchronous call of * ngIf?

**

> **I solved using this code:**

**

```
<div>
   <div *ngIf="imgDoc$ | async as item">
      <div *ngIf="item.photoURL; then noImgContainer;">
         <img [src]="item.photoURL"/> 
      </div>
      <ng-template #noImgContainer>
          Image Not Exists
      </ng-template>
  </div>
</div
```

I found the answer in this topic's answer: [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434313/angular-4-async-with-loading-and-display-when-empty)

Answer (score 2):

**I solved using this code:**

```
   <div>
   <div *ngIf="imgDoc$ | async as item">
      <div *ngIf="item.photoURL; then noImgContainer;">
         <img [src]="item.photoURL"/> 
      </div>
      <ng-template #noImgContainer>
          Image Not Exists
      </ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

> 

**I found the answer in this topic's answer:**
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434313/angular-4-async-with-loading-and-display-when-empty)