# Add a Loading message without an extra variable in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I have the following service method in Angular 7:

```
public getTopPosts(): Observable<Payload<PostResponse>> {

  return this.httpClient.get<Payload<PostResponse>>('/top-posts');

}
```

On the component I have:

```
export class TopPostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: PostModel[] = [];

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPosts();
  }

  getPosts() {

    this.postService.getTopPosts().subscribe((payload: Payload<PostResponse>) => {

      this.posts = payload.map((response: PostResponse) => { 
        return {
          id: response.id, 
          title: response.title
        };
      });

    });

  }
}
```

And the component HTML is:

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
  {{post.title}}  
</div>
```

It is working but I would like to display "Loading" while data is loading.

Is this possible without using an extra variable on my component?

Comment: yes it can possible. show message when posts is undefined.

Comment: What is the reason of not using an 'extra' (which is not) variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to mark this as a dupe so I'm posting a link to the similar question as an answer here [Angular 4 async with loading and display when empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434313/angular-4-async-with-loading-and-display-when-empty).

You would have to update your observable to use the async pipe though so it will be something like this:

```js
export class TopPostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts$: Observable<PostModel[]>;

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPosts();

    this.posts$ = this.postService.getTopPosts().pipe(
      map((payload: Payload<PostResponse>) => {
        return payload.map((response: PostResponse) => { id: response.id, title: response.title});
      })
    );
  }

}


<div *ngIf="(posts$ | async)?.length > 0; else loading">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async">
     <div>{{post.title}}</div>
   <ng-container>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>loading posts...</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not initialize `posts: PostModel[]` and use an `<div *ngIf="!posts" >loading...</div>`. Also as Osakr pointed out in the comments: set `this.posts` to `[]` because otherwise it would keep loading if the call fails.

Your new code would look like this:

```
export class TopPostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: PostModel[];

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPosts();
  }

  getPosts() {

    this.postService.getTopPosts().subscribe((payload: Payload<PostResponse>) => {

      this.posts = payload.map((response: PostResponse) => { 
        return {
          id: response.id, 
          title: response.title
        };
      },
      error => { this.posts = [] }
      );

    });

  }
}
```

And the HTML is:

```
<div *ngIf="!posts">
  loading...
</div>
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
  {{post.title}}  
</div>
```

Comment: What if you fail requesting the data, then posts will remain `undefined` and you'll have a cool spinner for the whole eternity

Comment: You can set `posts` to `[]` in the onError of the subscribe


      `error => {
        this.posts = [];
      }`

Comment: Which at the end is the same than having a isLoading variable. ( I didn't wanted to be rude, just wanted to make the creator of the post realize that having a variable for loading purposes is not bad ). Your answer is good, anyways you should add more information i guess

Comment: That's true, also a `loading` variable would be clearer if there are multiple people working on the same code.
I'll add some more information to the answer.