# Show message if Observable has no items afters loading

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

On an Angular 7 application I have the following:

```
<div *ngIf="(posts$ | async)?.length > 0; else loader">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async">
    posts contents
  </ng-container>
</div>
<ng-template #loader>
  Loading ...
</ng-template>
```

Sometimes **after loading** there are no posts ...

In that case I would like to show a message saying "Posts not found".

How can I do this?

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434313/angular-4-async-with-loading-and-display-when-empty/46434718#46434718

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 async with loading and display when empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434313/angular-4-async-with-loading-and-display-when-empty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it like this:

```
<div *ngIf="(posts$ | async) as posts; else loader">
  <div *ngIf="posts.length > 0; else noposts">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let post of posts">
      posts contents
    </ng-container>
  </div>
  <ng-template #noposts>
    No posts
  </ng-template>
</div>
<ng-template #loader>
  Loading ...
</ng-template>
```